# Macro to copy and paste rows to another worksheet without it pasting miles down the page

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I have been developing a macro, driven by a button within my worksheet, where I can copy rows, and paste them, onto the next available line of another worksheet , when certain criteria are met within a certain column.

The problem I have is that when the macro runs, it does copy and paste onto the other spreadsheet, however, it is pasting into the 8000th row even though there are only ever, on average, 150-200 tasks on the destination sheet.

Also, further to this, it only pastes into the 8000th row and, therefore, overwrites anything already in the row.

I want the macro to run concurrently so that it simply pastes into the next available row each time, and then continues to find the next new row instead of overwriting other rows.

I do have formatting within my log but only in the sense of borders and a couple of data validation dropdown lists.

The code I have developed is below:

```
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim K As Long
I = Worksheets("Demand Log").UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = Worksheets("Change Log").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If J = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Change Log").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Demand Log").Range("O5:O" & I)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Change Team" Then
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Change Log").Range("A" & J + 0)
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

If anyone can help with the development of this macro it would be much appreciated.

It would also be great if the macro could copy and paste into the destination spreadsheet, but also copy the row to a third spreadsheet before deleting the row from the source sheet.

Many thanks

Comment: What would the following achieve J + 0? Nothing. It is J. And what happens when J =0? I am worried you will be attempting to work with a non existent row 0 .

Comment: I suspect    On Error Resume Next this not being closed is hiding errors and i would be careful with using UsedRange to determine rows.

Comment: And you should delete rows backwards or you may end up deleting incorrectly.

Comment: What happens to Worksheets("Demand Log").Range("O5:O" & I) if I is less than 5?

Comment: So I took an existing code and have tried to adapt and develop it to work for my workbook. I am an advanced excel user, however an amateur when it comes to the world of macros and therefore am trying to self teach.

Comment: "I do have formatting within my log but only in the sense of borders and a couple of data validation dropdown lists." - `UsedRange` reflects what range has been used in your worksheet, even if you have only used it to put some borders or data validation dropdown lists.

Comment: Welcome! _Everybody has to start somewhere!_  As suggested above, the first step is to **remove or comment-out** the error handling line `On Error Resume Next` since that prevents you from seeing errors.  In the development stage you *want* to know when something's going wrong.  I would also suggest adding a line at the top of each/any module: `Option Explicit` and then re-compile the VBA (Debug > Compile).  This forces you to make sure that variables and properly declared and handled.  Also, check out the [tour] as well as [mcve].

Comment: That's fine. The above are just some suggestions to bear in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `UsedRange` to find the last used row in a spreadsheet, especially if you have formatted cells that you don't want to consider as being "used".

A more reliable way would be something like:

```
J = Worksheets("Change Log").Cells(Worksheets("Change Log").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

(replacing `"A"` with whatever column you have that will always contain data in a "used" row)

---

Your code is also calculating `J` once, and then constantly pasting new information to that Jth row.  You need to increment J each time you write a row to the destination.

Perhaps use:

```
J = J + 1
```

just before

```
xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Change Log").Range("A" & J)
```

---

(The problems that will occur with the row deletion, which aren't mentioned in your question, can be addressed in another question if you can't work that out.  But there are already many questions/answers on Stack Overflow that will address that issue.)

Comment: So I have edited the VBA to incorporate what you advised. It is now working, however, if I have 4 tasks that need pasting across, its removing two but only pasting one across. Is there anything in my code to suggest that this would happen?

Comment: @Adamlh77 Yes, the fact that you are processing your deletes from the first row to the last row, instead of the opposite direction.  Oops - no - that would explain them not all being copied/deleted, but not some being deleted without being copied.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I go about changing that?

Comment: @Adamlh77 It would be a good idea to post the new issue as a new question - good Stack Overflow questions ask about **one** issue - because many, many people might have that same issue in the future, but very few people will have the same combination of multiple issues.  And Stack Overflow is more about having answers available to future searchers than just solving the problem for the first person that has the issue.

Comment: I see, no worries,  I will post a new one, thank you

Comment: Actually - the `J` is the reason that only one is being copied but multiple ones are being deleted.  I will edit the answer to explain that one, because that **is** somewhat related to the current question.

Comment: @Adamlh77 OK, edited the answer to fix up the issue with `J`.  You will still have problems due to deleting rows in ascending order (i.e. if you have two rows beneath each other, both of which should be moved, it will only process the first one), but that needs to be a different question.

Comment: - Thank you. The above amendment seems to have fixed the issue. I still have to click the linked button a couple of times as its only pasting a few at a time, which is better than nothing but every entry is now pasting successfully which was the main aim :)